# Android - Custom App Themes that are freely available

Tags: android

I want to make my Android app look a little bit sexier but as I don't have knack for design I was wondering if there are other themes that are available for importing into your Android app (like the Dark and Light themes that come with SDK)?

I do not expect a Theme that would make Android app look like an iPhone app, but anything that would help me  move in that direction is a welcome suggestion (and please don't go with "you can create theme on your own").

Comment: marked as answered just to preserve the info... if anyone has better answer, please let me know

Comment: Did u find any website where i can find some themes to download .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what you call the "dark and light themes" are built-in styles that will make apps look different if chosen - but only, if the apps use the standard-look of e.g. buttons!

Whatever comes up when searching the web for "android themes" are pages like this (e.g.): android-themes.net, but as you want to style your app this doesn't seem to be the right place, as they only offer "OS themes" which will style your desktop and not your apps.

What you can do: create (or get) graphics for whatever elements you like styled and include those graphics in your app (inside your resource-dirs, watch out for different screen resolutions). There are loads of sites with free graphics if you can't make them on your own (e.g. www.freeiconsdownload.com has some cool icons to make you app fancy, they just ask to name their site if you use them for commercial purposes).

On the other hand (apart from graphics, icons, etc.), you can style your views using styles similar to CSS in HTML:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: when I type "android themes", I get OS skins, not application themes for developers.